# Mocking a lambda layer library for unit testing fails in jest

Tags: unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to unit test my lambda using jest. In the lambda code, we have a line of code that relies on a package situated in the lambda layer.

```
import { logger } from 'opt/nodejs/logger';
...
logger.debug('a message');
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'debug')
```

Based on the [jest documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/), the attribute `moduleNameMapper` is the way to go to be able to mock a library but it didn't work for me.

I have this folder structure:

[image]

The lambda layer contains the lib folder.

This is the content of `jest.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  modulePaths: ['node_modules', '.'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^opt/nodejs/logger$': '<rootDir>/../lib/src/logger.ts',
  },
}
```

I also tried to put an absolute path (something like `/User/.../lib/src/logger.ts`) and `'^opt/nodejs/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../lib/src//$1'` but still didn't work.

I feel like this is a kind of a problem where you're missing a very small detail, any idea how to fix this? alternatively, is there another way to do the mocking easily?

Comment: Can't reproduce. It works fine for me. You can provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and GitHub repo

Answer (score 0):

After I got enough of trying with the config in `jest.config.js`, I switched to try with `jest.mock()` and iI got it working using:

```
jest.mock('opt/nodejs/logger', () => ({
  logger: {
    debug: jest.fn((msg: string) => console.log('debug message: ', msg)),
    info: jest.fn((msg: string) => console.log('info message: ', msg)),
    error: jest.fn((msg: string) => console.log('error message: ', msg)),
    warn: jest.fn((msg: string) => console.log('warning message: ', msg)),
  },
}));
```